# Grammatically correct use of is come and has come

Tags: sentence-construction

"Get down, our destination has come"

Is the above sentence construction is correct? If yes can I construct sentence using Has come as below?

a) "Get down, our Stop / Station has come"

Also, Would it be correct if I construct the sentence as below?

b) "Get down, our Stop / Station is come"

For me both have same meaning, that we have reached our stop and now need to get down.  "Is Come" Is more like information and " Has come" gives information of completed process of reaching.

Comment: What do you mean by "get down"? Go down? Get off?

Comment: *station **is** come* is surprisingly correct structure...though biblical!

Answer (score 1):

> "Get down"

This is how you tell a dog to stop jumping up to lick your face. You don't use it to address people about to leave a train.
It's additionally used in war movies when the enemy starts shooting. It's a command, not a polite request.

> "our destination has come"

The destination hasn't travelled anywhere. The train did.
When you get to your destination, you have **arrived**.

If it's a group of friends, family, then something along the lines of

> "This is our stop"
>   "We've arrived [at our destination]"

would be quite sufficient.
Informally, you just **get off** the train at your stop. You could 'get down from it' but that's more describing the act of actually stepping down from the train to the platform.

The more formal term to use for leaving a train, if 'leave' is not plain enough, is to **alight** - more likely to be used by the train driver or other official.

> "This train has reached its final destination. Would all passengers please alight here."

Comment: Well, you can *get down* from some elevated place, like a train car or the bed of a truck.  But you are right and this is not the common idiom to instruct someone to *get off* or *disembark* from a vehicle.

Comment: Yes, as already noted [I ran a few edits quickly in the first few mins]. I'd keep embark/disembark for ships, though; board/alight for trains.

Comment: On the local rail lines they use *detrain*, although I think that might sound weird to some.

Comment: It sounds weird to me, for sure... it sounds almost involuntary & potentially dangerous, like derail ;)

Comment: And yet *deplane* is fine.  Weird, isn't it?

Comment: That one's weird to me too - dictionary says it's US. I'm Br E, never heard it before. They used to use disembark here for planes, I get the feeling these days they just use 'leave'; though i used to travel on the Nationals, long-haul, these days it's just the budgets, short-haul/holidays.